# foreach statement only returning 1 item

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, foreach

I'm using sessions to store products viewed, but I'm having a problem printing out all of the items when I query the database.

Controller

```
$hello_world = $this->session->all_userdata();


foreach($hello_world as $key=>$product_id) {
 $query['products']  = $this->Global_products->globalFindProducts($product_id);

  echo $product_id; // Right here it echos all the items in the session.

 }
```

Model

```
function globalFindProducts($product_id) 
{
$this->db->join('price','product.modelNumber = price.modelNumber','left')->where('product.modelNumber',$product_id);
$this->db->group_by('product.modelNumber');
$query = $this->db->get('by.product');
return $query->result();
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
<div><?php echo $product->name; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

In my view I can only see one item, not all of them. Can someone please give me your advice as to how you would approach solving this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the var_dump($products), does it have all the products or only one product.

Comment: It has the last item in the session array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I haven't really coded in CodeIgniter, so its a best guess:

Controller

```
$hello_world = $this->session->all_userdata();

foreach($hello_world as $key=>$product_id) {
    $query['products'][]  = $this->Global_products->globalFindProducts($product_id);
    echo $product_id; // Right here it echos all the items in the session.
}
```

Note: Here I'm making the `$query['products']` an array, so all results from
`$this->Global_products->globalFindProducts($product_id);` are stored

Answer (score 0):

Where are you sharing your databases results to the view?

Normally, you will want to use something like:

```
$data['hello_world'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

Then when calling the view, include that data array:

```
$this->load->view('someview', $data);
```

Thus, inside your view you can run a for loop:

```
<?php foreach($hello_world as $product) { ?>
<div><?php echo $product->name; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```